# Images break the spoiler code.

Tags: bug, status-completed, spoilers

I think images break the spoiler code.  I'm not sure when or how often an image might need to be placed in a spoiler block, but can this be fixed?

> [image]

Comment: is this an actual or theoretical problem? Can you point to a real world instance of this that isn't hypothetical?

Comment: @Jeff - Would this question not be a "real-world instance"?  The point here is, the code's broken.  Whether anyone may or may not run into this issue in the "production environment" is anyone's guess, but the bug is there regardless.

Comment: I think Jeff Atwood's reluctance here is that spoilerizing images would require a different method of spoiler generation (at the moment it's the simplest implementation possible: make the text the same color as the background). Plus, there's a work-around: link to the image, instead of including it inline.

Comment: @AceCalhoon - I understand that, and am not arguing the point.  My only reason for posting this was to make sure that the issue has not gone unnoticed.  If it's a bug they're willing to accept, because most users will probably never see it, then it's an entirely understandable position for them to take and they're fully within their rights to do so.  But, I feel it would have been irresponsible of me to have noticed this and *not* reported it.

Comment: I predict that you will get a `status-bydesign` on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers now hide on hover via a different mechanism, as a result images are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I predict that you will get a `status-bydesign` on this one.